# SQL query only selecting first result

Tags: python, sql, user-input

I want to retrieve all *songIDs* that are associated with the *userID* that I input but it only prints the first result.

database:
[image]

My code:

```
enter = raw_input('Enter UserID: ')
cursor = MusicData.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT songID FROM train WHERE userID=? )"
result = cursor.execute(sql,(enter,))
print result.fetchall()[0][0],
```

```
Enter UserID: 3a613180775197cd08c154abe4e3f67af238a632
SODOZXB12A8C13CD55
```

Comment: Your `SELECT *` subquery looks unnecessary, but in any case you should check your data, because it appears this user only has one song associated with him.

Comment: Fetchall gets all the songs that matched. You're printing only the first of them. Try printing the output of fetchall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your print statement. Right now by giving print `result.fetchall()[0][0]` you are asking python to print one element.  Use

```
for item in result.fetchall():
    print item
```

Answer (score 1):

You're only showing the first rows first column due to
`[0][0]` after in this line `print result.fetchall()[0][0]`

Answer (score 0):

Add "LIMIT NN" to your SQL request. That will limit an output to NN number of rows:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM Table LIMIT 5"
```

Will give you only 5 rows.

on MS SQL DB it should be the "TOP" keyword:

```
sql = "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table"
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by adding a for loop of fetchall()

```
rows = result.fetchall()
for row in rows:
    print row
```